# How to read one character at a time from text file

Tags: c++, file-io, char

Here is my function that has the following code in it. Note: It's already declared in the main and runs perfectly fine.

```
void displaySeatingChart(char seats[][colvalue], float prices[rowvalue])
{
    string filename = "seatingChart.dat";
    ifstream inFile(filename);

    for (rows = 1; rows <= rowvalue; rows++)
    {
        string newLine;
        cout << "Row #" << rows << "\t";
        for (cols = 1; cols <= colvalue; cols++)
        {
            inFile >> newLine;
            cout << newLine;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

`rows` is 15 and `cols` is 30. My problem is that the `cout << newline` prints literally the entire file (which is basically all #). How can I print just 15 characters and not like 1500?

Answer (score 3):

```
inFile >> newLine;
```

This reads everything until a whitespace character. If your file contains all the characters in one line and contains no white spaces, it makes sense that the above line reads the contents of the entire file.

To read one character at a time, use

```
char c = inFile.get();
```

Your inner loop would be:

```
for (cols = 1; cols <= colvalue; cols++)
{
    char c = inFile.get();
    cout << c;
}
```

See the documentation for [`istream::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) for additional info.